# image in a brand new jframe?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I am simply looking for a class that will create a new jframe displaying the image "rules.jpg" which is found in the src folder of my project.

**edit**: i worked out how to do this just there, but the image STILL wont display when i export it to a jar, does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

To load the image from a jar, you will need to access it differently.  There is nice Swing tutorial for doing exactly that:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource

Here is some relevant code form the tutorial:

```
java.net.URL imageURL = myDemo.class.getResource("images/myImage.gif");
...
if (imageURL != null) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
}
```

Comment: I am wary of getting the wrong class loader when using the 'myDemo.class' form of getResource().  Instead I generally use 'this.getClass()', which **forces** me to do it within an instance of a custom class - thereby gaining the context class loader.